# How do I figure out why my Struts 2 action hasn't been mapped?

Tags: java, struts2, struts-config

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13978955/there-is-no-action-mapped-for-namespace-and-action-name-tutorial)

When I try to hit my Struts 2 action, I get the following error message:

```
There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name getTutorial. - [unknown    location]
```

I am using Eclipse indigo IDE, Tomcat 7 and JDK 1.7. The jar files I included are commons-logging-1.0.4.jar, freemarker-2.3.8.jar, ognl- 2.6.11.jar, struts2-core-2.0.11.jar, xwork-2.0.4.jar. I placed the struts.xml in classes folder in WEB-INF and I also tried it placing in
src folder but I could not able to make it.

## struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration  
  2.0//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
  <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="tutorial" class="com.test.TutorialAction">
      <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
      <result name="failure">/failure.jsp</result>
    </action>
  </package>
</struts>
```